# AspNetCore.HealthCheck in Azure function always returns 200 even when unhealthy

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-functions, health-check

We have an Azure Function using .Net Core 7 that we've added a HealthCheck to. The healthcheck fires, if the status is set to unhealthy, we return a an instance of `ServiceUnavailableObjectResult`. The HTTP status code always returns 200 regardless of what we return.

From *Program.cs*

```
services.AddHealthChecks()
    .AddUrlGroup(
        uri: new Uri($"{baseAddress}/health"),
        name: "Mgmt")
    .AddAzureBlobStorage(
        connectionString: context.Configuration.GetValue<string>(RecipientUploadOptions.BlobConnectionStringName),
        containerName: context.Configuration.GetValue<string>(RecipientUploadOptions.IncomingContainerName),
        name: "IncomingBlobContainer")
    .AddAzureBlobStorage(
        connectionString: context.Configuration.GetValue<string>(RecipientUploadOptions.BlobConnectionStringName),
        containerName: context.Configuration.GetValue<string>(RecipientUploadOptions.ErrorContainerName),
        name: "ErrorBlobContainer")
    .AddAzureBlobStorage(
        connectionString: context.Configuration.GetValue<string>(RecipientUploadOptions.BlobConnectionStringName),
        containerName: context.Configuration.GetValue<string>(RecipientUploadOptions.ArchiveContainerName),
        name: "ArchiveBlobContainer");
```

From *HealthCheckFunction.cs*

```
[Function("health")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Health([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData z)
{
    var status = await _healthCheckService.CheckHealthAsync();
    if (status.Status == HealthStatus.Healthy)
    {
        return new OkObjectResult(Enum.GetName(typeof(HealthStatus), status.Status));
    }

    return new ServiceUnavailableObjectResult(Enum.GetName(typeof(HealthStatus), status.Status));
}
```

Expected:

- The HTTP status code returned is 503 - Service Unavailable along with the payload.

Actual:

- The HTTP status code returned os 200 - OK along with the payload
- The same code used for HealthChecks in web API projects return 503 as expected

[image: Screen capture of a Google Chrome browser instance and nertwork showing the HTTP ststus of 200 and the JSON body indicating a 503 error result]

Any suggestions would be greatly appreaciated

Comment: Since you are using .NET 7 (and hence isolated workers) with ASP.NET types, you need perform a few steps as mentioned in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#aspnet-core-integration-preview). Could you confirm if you have followed these?

Comment: @PramodValavala Those instructions to do not appear to be accurate. Browsing in the NuGet Package Manager UI for "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" returns "No packages found".

Comment: @PramodValavala It helps if I have "Include pre-release" checked.

However, following those instructions causes the request to the health check to never complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you can develop HTTP functions when using .NET Isloted Worker.

##### [Built-in HTTP Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#built-in-http-model)

For this you need to return the [HttpResponseData](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.functions.worker.http.httpresponsedata?view=azure-dotnet) type as follows

```cs
[Function(nameof(Health))]
public async Task<HttpResponseData> Health([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req)
{
    var response = req.CreateResponse();

    var status = await _healthCheckService.CheckHealthAsync();

    await response.WriteAsJsonAsync(
        Enum.GetName(typeof(HealthStatus), status.Status),
        status.Status == HealthStatus.Healthy ? HttpStatusCode.OK : HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable
    );

    return response;
}
```

##### [ASP.NET Core integration (preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#aspnet-core-integration-preview)

There are a few pre-requisites to get this model to work which are documented in the doc linked above. Here are the same for reference.

1. Install the [Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore/1.0.0-preview2) NuGet package, version 1.0.0-preview2 or later (Note that you must check the `include prerelease` checkbox in Visual Studio)

   Also, make sure [Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk/1.11.0) is version 1.11.0 or later and   [Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker/1.16.0) is version 1.16.0 or later.
2. Replace `ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults` with `ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication` in `Program.cs`
3. Use `HttpRequest` and `IActionResult` types from ASP.NET
4. Add the `AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags` app setting with value `EnableHttpProxying`

Answer (score 0):

Here is implementation based on Pramod's [answer here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1328970/aspnetcore-healthcheck-in-azure-function-always-re?page=1&orderby=helpful#answers).

```
[Function(nameof(Health))]
public async Task<HttpResponseData> Health([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req)
{
    //HACK (Work around)
    //Due to a behavior in the Azure Function framework for health checks
    //will always return a 200 regardless of state and ignore the
    //IActionResult. The solution--for now--is to get closer to the metal
    //and write our own response body. ASP.NET Core integration (for Azure
    //Functions) is still in preview (and not solving the problem for us
    //right this moment but may hold the key for doing this better in the
    //future.

    var response = req.CreateResponse();

    var status = await _healthCheckService.CheckHealthAsync();

    var httpStatus = (status.Status == HealthStatus.Healthy
        ? HttpStatusCode.OK
        : HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable);

    var statusResult = new
    {
        Value = Enum.GetName(typeof(HealthStatus), status.Status),
        Formatters = new string[] { },
        // Entries = status.Entries,
        // ^^^^ This would be nice but doesn't directly serialize and will
        // throw a NotSupportedException. That may be useful to explore
        // since it gives details about what is unhealthy
        ContentType = "application/json",
        StatusCode = httpStatus
    };

    await response.WriteAsJsonAsync(statusResult, httpStatus);

    return response;
}
```